# How do I remove parentheses and single quotation marks from my output?

Tags: python

How do I remove parentheses and single quotation marks from my output? There is no requirement in my code to show brackets and single quotation marks.

```py
person = "    xx   "
what_he_said = "    abc！"
print(f"{person.split()}曾经说过，“{what_he_said.split()}”")
```

This is the actual output:

```
['xx']曾经说过，“['abc！']”
```

I don't want to output the middle brackets and quotation marks.
I'm using Python 3.10, the IDE is pycharm.

[image: ][1]]

Comment: Why are you using `split` in the first place? It returns a list of strings instead of a single string. Try `''.join(person.split())` to connect the items back without any separators or figure out what you actually want and write that without `split`.

Comment: As suggested in the answer, you are probably trying to remove spaces and should use `strip`. If yo want to use `split` for some reason, it would be something like `print(f"{''.join(person.split())}曾经说过，“{''.join(what_he_said.split())}”")`

Comment: Split is a way to split your string into a list by a delimeter. For example, `'abc:123:test'.split(':')` will return `['abc', '123', 'test']`. It is not what you need.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP needs to show some effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of split is a list. If you want the str without surrounding space, you should use `strip`

```py
person = "    xx   "
what_he_said = "    abc！"
print(f"{person.strip()}曾经说过，“{what_he_said.strip()}”")
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Just to print you can try:

- Supposing it's necessary to use `.split()`

```
person = "    xx   "
what_he_said = "    abc！"
print(*person.split(),'曾经说过',*what_he_said.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

The split() function will separate the data with the [sep] parameter, it's empty by default, I assume you're using split to remove "[space-k]", but note that it will always return a separate argument list

```
"hola como estas ".split(sep=" ")
```

will return:

```
[hola, como, estas]
```

If you really need to use the split() function, you can get its values with the index.

E.g

```
person = "    xx   "
what_he_said = "    abc！"
print(f"{person.split()[0]}曾经说过，“{what_he_said.split()[0]}”")
```

will return:

```
xx曾经说过，“abc！”
```